# Variable point size depending on data in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to plot points with a variable point size on a map using QGIS. The point size is decided by the third column in the .csv file I add.

Adding the points works just fine by using the "add delimited text layer" option. After adding the points using lat/lon coordinates, they appear on the screen just fine. All points have the same size as expected. Then I try to alter the size by going to "Layer Options -> Symbology" and change it from "Single SymboL" to "Graduated" and then chose the third column of my added csv-file. After clicking apply, all the dots are gone. I am doing something wrong, but not sure what.

I don't have a map in the background for now, but don't think that should make a difference.

Example data:

```
lat,lon,value
53.994306,6.491222,1
53.987583,6.49125,2
53.980833,6.49125,3
53.974111,6.491278,4
53.994333,6.502667,5
53.987583,6.502667,6
53.980861,6.502694,7
53.974111,6.502694,8
53.967361,6.502722,9
53.994333,6.514083,10
```

Comment: Click "Classify" button after choosing the column -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQKGA.png

Comment: That was an easy fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

- After choosing the column, click on symbol as in the image:

  [image]
- Then, Click "**Data defined override**" button for **Size**, select `value` as in the following image

  [image]
- Finally, click on "**Classify**" button.

  [image]